# Converting table to div

Tags: html, css

I've used table to show text in 3 columns but on mobiles it doesn't fit in screen so I would rather use div.

It won't let me copy the code I used here, could I attached it in text edit here?

Appreciate the help

Comment: *"It won't let me copy the code I used here, could I attached it in text edit here?"* What does that mean? I can't imagine you're not able to copy and paste your markup... Also, "converting" a table to a series of divs is not the way you want to look at this. If it's only 3 columns, then it shouldn't be too difficult to rebuild your content from scratch using a `3-column div layout`

Comment: Anyway I think you just need to read about the `display` CSS property (fully) and you will find a way to convert your table to divs

Comment: 1. Paste the code, 2. Select the code, 3. Press the code-sample-icon `{ }`

Comment: guessing he is using design view not code view in Dreamweaver. :)

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to add the code that I was using in this post but it wouldn't show correctly. I've used a theme option to display it correctly using gallery. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS you can make table structure. In this solution I've used `display:table` and `display:table-cell` to make a table. these are not actual table. but using this property we can create a table layout.

Here is the CSS required to make a table layout. I've made a Dummy ***[Demo](http://jsbin.com/figedite/1/)***.

```
#main_table{display:table; padding:5px;}
.column1, .column2, .column3{display:table-cell; vertical-align:top;}
```

Here is the HTML Code for example.

```
<div id="main_table">
    <div class="column1">content will come here</div>
    <div class="column2">content will come here</div>
    <div class="column3">content will come here</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, in the end I've used my theme's option to add gallery with titles and descriptions.